# Class static fields declaration order

Tags: c++

I am trying to write simple logger class, and I ended up with singleton class design. Example bellow:

DataIO.h:

```
class DataIO
{
private:
   static DataIO instance;
public:
   static time_t date;
   static std::string path;
   static FILE* log;

private:
   DataIO()
   { 
      date = time(NULL);
      path = "#Output_" + std::to_string(date);
      std::string buffer = "mkdir " + path;
      system(buffer.c_str());
   };
   ~DataIO();
public:
   static DataIO getInstance() const { return instance; };
   static void restart();
};
```

DataIO.cpp:

```
time_t DataIO::date;
std::string DataIO::path;
FILE* DataIO::log;

DataIO DataIO::instance;
```

Do I have any guaranty about the order in with static fields will be initialized?? Usually i know i don't have any... 
 
But in this case my DataIO constructor require that those three static fields must be declared before constructor is called. **And therefore does it force the order in with static fields are declared??**

Comment: This is not a real singleton design. Usually, you wouldn't have `date`, `path`, and `log` be static. They would be instance fields, and you would instantiate `instance` once, and have a static method return it.

Comment: Jerfov2 I know they should not be static from the point of view of singleton class design, but I want to call them `DataIO::date` not `getInstance().data`

Comment: Then what is the point of even having `instance`?

Comment: Jerfov2, i don't realy need access to DataIO object, but i need this object to be created at the start of a program. It's constructor is calling `system("mkdir #Output_*** ")` where " *** " are `DataIO::date`. Ofc this is current date expressed in seconds. And the point to all of this is to create unique folder for the output. 
`DataIO::DataIO()` constructor is just the function in witch i can do all of it, at the start of a program without calling it explicitly.

Comment: One more thing c++ is missing: static constructors. Oh well. Maybe in future standards? ;)